# Troubleshooting an Application.OnTime Function in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that I need to run every 30 min from 6pm until 230pm the following day every day and I keep the sheet open.

Upon opening the sheet, its intended to schedule the UpdateCaller() macro for the next 30 min period. Once that runs, it basically checks if the current time falls within my constraints, if so call PopulateData then schedule for the next 30 min period and repeat.

For some reason - I can't get the actually Call PopulateDate to execute. I've added debug.print lines of code to both the worksheet.open macro and the updatecaller macro and the output is below. I see it outputing the next scheduled time so I know it's successfully running through both macros. Also, when I step into the macro and just hit F5, it runs correctly and PopulateData is called. I also had it working yesterday without any problems.

I've tried closing all excel sheets except this one, restarting excel, restarting the computer but nothing seems to be working.

Any ideas/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim t As Long
Dim opentime As Date

t = 24 / (30 / 60)
Application.OnTime TimeValue(Format(WorksheetFunction.Ceiling(Now * t, 1) / t, "HH:mm:ss")), "UpdateCaller"

opentime = TimeValue(Format(WorksheetFunction.Ceiling(Now * t, 1) / t, "HH:mm:ss"))
Debug.Print opentime

End Sub

Public Sub UpdateCaller()
    Dim tme As Date
    Dim t As Long

    If TimeValue(Format(Now, "HH:mm:ss")) <= TimeValue("14:30:00") Or TimeValue(Format(Now, "HH:mm:ss")) >= TimeValue("18:00:00") Then
        Call PopulateData
    End If

    t = 24 / (30 / 60)
    tme = TimeValue(Format(WorksheetFunction.Ceiling((Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")) * t, 1) / t, "HH:mm:ss"))
    Debug.Print "Procedure ""UpdateCaller"" will next run at: ", tme

    Application.OnTime tme, "UpdateCaller"
End Sub
```

[image]

---

---

Edit1: I've also added the following line of code right before Call PopulateData and at 1pm it didn't print that. It seems like for some reason when it's scheduled to run it's not entering that If statement but when I step through the code, it enters it just fine. Any thoughts about what could be wrong with that If statement?

```
Debug.Print "Entered Execution Block"
```

Edit: Is it possible that because I have the UpdateCaller in the ThisWorkbook Object and the actual PopulateDate in Module 1 it's causing issue?

Comment: I don't remember exactly, but I think for `Application.OnTime`, instead of just "UpdateCaller", I think it needs something like "ModuleName.UpdateCaller". And the  type of module the function resides in is important. Either the function needs to be in a general module, or it won't be called properly if it's in a general module...

Comment: Also, there are some optional arguments for whether it should keep trying or not when missed (which may need looking into, if there's any other VBA happening, or processes during which Excel is busy for a time.)

Comment: @Mistella I'm still very confused on the difference between the module and the This workbook objects. It seems like the Application.OnTime is correctly scheduling the UpdateCaller b/c it outputs the scheduled time but perhaps b/c the UpdateCaller is in the ThisWorkbook object and the PopulateData is in a module it's causing an issue. If I just move the PopulateData to the ThisWorkbook object - how will that affect my macro?

Comment: as for the other vba processes - I was thinking that might be the case as well however, it still wasn't running when it was the only worksheet open

Comment: Try this: change `Application.OnTime tme, "UpdateCaller"` to `Application.OnTime tme, "ThisWorkbook.UpdateCaller"` and `Application.OnTime TimeValue(Format(WorksheetFunction.Ceiling(Now * t, 1) / t, "HH:mm:ss")), "UpdateCaller"` to `Application.OnTime TimeValue(Format(WorksheetFunction.Ceiling(Now * t, 1) / t, "HH:mm:ss")), "ThisWorkbook.UpdateCaller"`

Comment: ^^ the suggested change is just adding "ThisWorkbook." to the beginning of the "UpdateCaller" string on both `Application.OnTime` calls.

Comment: Ok updated the code to reflect that. Do you mind taking a look at the first edit in the Edit section of the original post and let me know your thoughts (if you have time of course)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190928/discussion-between-mistella-and-novawaly).